# Efficient by-group processing of large dataset (accelerometry data with person-specific cut points) with user-built function in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, accelerometer

We are looking for ways to speed up a by-group processing task that relies on a function from a user-created package. The function we are using determines whether or not an observation (row) in a dataset should be classified as part of a bout of intense physical activity. The function evaluates every row in the dataset using a single criterion value (thresh.lower in the example below). Under typical use, this single criterion is applied to every observation in the dataset being processed. In our dataset, however, we have hundreds of groups of observations ("group" being repeated minute-level observations for one person), each with its own group-specific (i.e., person-specific) criterion value. Each group of consists of up to a year's worth of minute-level (~500K) observations.

Our current solution (sketched out at the bottom of this post) is to have each group of observations stored in a separate (person-specific) CSV file, with these CSV files stored in a single source directory. Then, using a for loop structure, we read in each file, feed the data through the function, take the function’s result (an integer vector of 0s and 1s with length = rows in source dataset), merge that result with the source dataset, and then output the merged data object to a destination directory. Ultimately, these separate person-level destination files are used to yield a single sample-level file containing sums computed by day, within person.

In the example immediately below, I first use the `accel.bouts` function on a single group's (person's) data just to demonstrate what the function does. Then I show an attempt at a dplyr-based approach that acts on a data frame containing data from all the groups (people). My goal was a vector (or column within a grouped dataset) with length = # groups (# of people) * # rows per group (rows per person) containing the `accel.bouts` output/result.

This attempt failed in at least two ways: (1) for each group in the grouped data frame/tibble(?) that is output, there are as many rows (14400) as there were for the entire data frame that was processed (thus 50*14440 rows total in the grouped data frame); and (2) the variable/column name corresponding to the function’s result ends up being a mishmash of the functions argument names.

I’m not wedded to the idea of a dplyr-based approach or a for loop or anything else at this point, so any and all suggestions that might speed up the workflow are welcome. Thanks!

```
# Loading accelerometry package, which contains accel.bouts function
library(accelerometry)

# Creating example 50-person (i.e., 50-group) file with 2880 minute-level observations per person
ids <- seq(101, 150)
minute_seq <- (seq.POSIXt(ISOdatetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, tz = ""), 
                          ISOdatetime(2017, 12, 2, 23, 59, 0, tz = ""), "min"))
participant_id <- rep(ids, each = length(minute_seq))
minute_ts <- rep(minute_seq, length(ids))
count_vm <- sample(0:3000, length(minute_ts), replace = TRUE)
wear <- rep(1, length(participant_id))
thresh <- rep(seq(from = 1551, to = (1550 + length(ids))), each = length(minute_seq))
df.all <- as.data.frame(cbind(participant_id, minute_ts, count_vm, wear, thresh))

## Demonstrating how function normally works, using a single person’s (group’s) data ##

# Creating example 1-person file with 2880 minute-level observations
df.101 <- subset(df.all, participant_id == 101)
# Generating vector of length 2880, containing 0s and 1s
# thresh.lower argument must be single value, hence the mean call
bout.101 <- accel.bouts(counts = df.101$count_vm, weartime = df.101$wear, bout.length = 5, 
                        thresh.lower = mean(df.101$thresh), thresh.upper = 1000000,
                        tol = 2, tol.lower = 1, tol.upper = Inf, nci = TRUE, 
                        days.distinct = FALSE, skipchecks = FALSE)

## Showing attempt at by-group processing ##

# Attempt at applying accel.bouts function by participant_id (group)
bout.all <- (df.all %>%
  group_by(participant_id) %>%
  do(., bout.min <- data.frame(accel.bouts(counts = df.all$count_vm, weartime = df.all$wear, 
                                           bout.length = 5, thresh.lower = mean(df.all$thresh), 
                                           thresh.upper = 1000000, tol = 2, 
                                           tol.lower = 1, tol.upper = Inf,
                                           nci = TRUE, days.distinct = FALSE, 
                                           skipchecks = FALSE)))) # Yields (50*50*2880) x 2 data frame
```

--

Here is a sketch of the set up we are currently using:

```
library(accelerometry)
library(tools)

in.path <- "/home/CSVIn/"
# Naming the directory path for the output datasets
out.path <- "/home/CSVOut/"
# Reading in Cutpoint table
cut.table <- read.csv(file = "/home/datetable/DateTable.csv", header = TRUE)
# Creating a list of the filenames for the input datasets
file.names <- dir(in.path, pattern = "*.csv")

## Looping through the bout-minute algorithm
## includes various data processing/cleaning steps
## as well as step for writing out a dataset for each person
##
for (i in 1:length(file.names)) {
  # Reading in an individual input dataset
  in.file <- read.csv(paste(in.path, file.names[i], sep = ""), header = TRUE)

  # Ensuring that observations are sorted by minute-level time stamp
  in.file.sort <- in.file[order(in.file$minute_ts), ]

  # Extracting participant ID-specific cutpoint value from
  # cutpoint table and creating MVPA threshold value to use
  # as "thresh.lower" argument in accel.bouts function call
  idnum <- mean(in.file.sort$participant_id)
  id.slice <- subset(cut.table, PID == idnum)
  cut <- id.slice$Cutpoint
  mvpa.thresh <- cut + 1

  ## Generating vector of bout minute indicator values (0=non-bout minute, 1=bout minute)
  ## Cutpoint (thresh.lower) = participant-specific cutpoint value from cutpoint table
  bout.mat <- accel.bouts(counts = in.file.sort$ count_vector_magnitude, 
                          weartime = in.file.sort$wear, bout.length = 5, 
                          thresh.lower = mvpa.thresh, thresh.upper = 1000000, 
                          tol = 2, tol.lower = 1, tol.upper = Inf, nci = TRUE, 
                          days.distinct = FALSE, skipchecks = FALSE)

  ## Adding bout minute indicator to input dataset as "bout.min"
  bout.min.df <- data.frame(bout.mat)
  names(bout.min.df) <- c("bout.min")
  in.file.bout <- cbind(in.file.sort, bout.min.df)

  # Writing CSV output file to output directory with same filename stem
  # as input file, but with "_bout" suffix
  out.name <- paste(file_path_sans_ext(basename(file.names[i])), "_bout.csv", sep = "")
  write.csv(in.file.bout,
    file = paste(out.path, out.name, sep = ""),
    row.names = FALSE, fileEncoding = "windows-1252"
  )
}
```

Comment: Questions that are only about how to use R are generally off topic here. This may be on topic on [SO]. I'll try migrating it there.